# where to place user-library in the manifest file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, emulation

I was reading a book and the author asked to add one user library and one user-permission to the manifest file as follows:

```
<uses-library android:name=”com.google.android.gtalkservice”/>
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.GTALK”/>
```

My questions are:

1. Where to place the user library correctly in the manifest file, i
   tried to place it right after the user permissions but eclipse
   highligted as error?
2. The GTALK user permission is not listed in the
   user permissions list, so how to add such user permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where to place the user library correctly in the manifest file, i tried to place it right after the user permissions but eclipse highligted as error

`<uses-library>` must be a child of `<application>`, and usually appears as the first child.

Note that `com.google.android.gtalkservice`, if it even exists, is not documented. Your book author should not be promoting its use.

> the GTALK user permission is not listed in the user permissions list, so how to add such user permission?

You should not be using such a permission, for the same reason that you should not be using that library. You are welcome to try simply pasting in that XML element to your manifest, but whether or not it will work is another matter entirely. There does not appear to be such a permission, even undocumented.

Comment: concerning the user-library tag , should i place it before or after the activity tag, because the activity tag is also a child of the application tag

Comment: @Amr: As noted in my answer, the `<uses-library>` tag is usually the first child of the `<application>` tag. AFAIK, that is not *absolutely* required, but I would recommend placing it there unless you have a good reason to try otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You may need the emulator with Google APIs to use Gtalk Service. [Manifest docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) says that the  tag has to be mentioned inside the application tag. Hope this helps.